# Convert Dictionary to Numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dictionary, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to convert the dictionary

```
{0: {0: 173, 1: 342, 2: 666, 3: 506, 4: 94},
 1: {0: 13, 1: 2171, 2: 1915, 3: 3075, 4: 630},
 2: {0: 0, 1: 265, 2: 5036, 3: 508, 4: 11},
 3: {0: 0, 1: 3229, 2: 2388, 3: 3649, 4: 193},
 4: {0: 3, 1: 151, 2: 591, 3: 1629, 4: 410}}
```

to numpy array

```
array([[ 173,  342,  666,  506,   94],
       [  13, 2171, 1915, 3075,  630],
       [   0,  265, 5036,  508,   11],
       [   0, 3229, 2388, 3649,  193],
       [   3,  151,  591, 1629,  410]])
```

Any ideas how to do it efficiently?

Comment: Efficient in terms of what? Speed, memory, cpu-cycles, readability, etc?

Comment: readibility mostly, speed and memory are on second place

Comment: `np.array([list(inner_dict.values()) for inner_dict in d.values()])`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Python-level loop is unavoidable here, so you can use a list comprehension:

```
res = np.array([list(item.values()) for item in d.values()])

# array([[ 173,  342,  666,  506,   94],
#        [  13, 2171, 1915, 3075,  630],
#        [   0,  265, 5036,  508,   11],
#        [   0, 3229, 2388, 3649,  193],
#        [   3,  151,  591, 1629,  410]])
```

As per @FHTMitchell's comment, this assumes your dictionary items (inner and outer) are ordered appropriately. Dictionaries are insertion ordered in 3.6 as a CPython implementation detail, and officially in 3.7+.

One way to define an order for inner *and* outer dictionaries is via [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
getter = itemgetter(*range(5))
res = np.array([getter(item) for item in getter(d)])
```

Such a solution does not depend on the order of your input dictionary.

Comment: nb this only works in python 3.6 or later and only if your dictionaries are constructed such that they are ordered.